# Mongo DB - query nested arrays of objects in referenced document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have few referenced collections: Employees, Roles, Schools...

I need to query the database, to list all employees that are employed by a certain school. That means all Employees, that has certain School ID in their corresponding role document must be returned in the list or array of results.

So far I have tried to find it like this:

```
const employees = mongoose.schema("Employees");
employees.find({})
  .populate({
    "path": "roles"
  })
  .then(function(docs){
    docs.filter(function(){
      // write my filters here.... 
    })
  });
```

but this still is inefficient and I can't make it work. 
It has to be a smarter way...

This is my Employee document, which references a document in Roles Collection:

```
{ 
    "_id" : { "$oid" : "57027f1b9522d363243abr42" }, 
      "assignedRoles": [
        {
          "type": "teacher",
          "schools": [
            {
              "schoolId": "57027f1b9522d3632423rf32",
              "classes" : ["math", "science"],
              "active": true
            },
            {
              "schoolId": "57027f1b9522d36324252fs2",
              "classes" : ["science"],
              "active": true
            },
            {
              "schoolId": "57027f1b9522d36324242f35",
              "classes" : ["math"],
              "active": true
            },
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "manager",
          "schools": [
            {
              "schoolId": "57027f1b9522d3632423rf32",
              "active": true
            },
            {
              "schoolId": "57027f1b9522d36324252fs2",
              "active": true
            }
          ]
        }
        {
          "type": "principal",
          "schools": [
            {
              "schoolId": "57027f1b9522d3632423rf32",
              "active": true
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "rolesMeta": "Meta Info for the Roles" 
    }
```

The following is the list of Schools - irrelevant for the task, I am just adding that for the completion:

```
{
  "_id": { "$oid" : "57027f1b9522d3632423rf32" },
  "name": "G.Washington HS",
  "district": "six",
  "state": "New Mexico"
},
{
  "_id": { "$oid" : "57027f1b9522d36324252fs2" },
  "name": "A. Lincoln HS",
  "district": "six",
  "state": "New Mexico"
},
{
  "_id": { "$oid" : "57027f1b9522d36324242f35" },
  "name": "T. Roosvelt HS",
  "district": "four",
  "state": "New Mexico"
}
```

Comment: is that pure MongoDB? Mongoose?

Comment: I am working on Mongoose, you are right. 
Let me correct my find() method ...

Comment: I have found the solution and will be posting here later today.

Comment: Posted the resolution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Resolution to the problem is to use [MongoDB Aggregate framework](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) to be able to drill down and "flatten" the array structure.

Here is how I have resolved it:

```
db.employees.aggregate([
     // I use $project to specify which field I want selected from the collection
    { 
      $project: {_id: 1, "roles": 1} 
    },
     // $lookup helps me get results and populate the 'role' field from the Roles collection. This returns an array
    {
      $lookup: {
        "from": "roles",
        "localField": "roles",
        "foreignField": "_id",
        "as": "roles"
      }
    },
     // $unwind is self explanatory - it flattens the array and creates multiple objects, instances of the parent object for each array element.
    {
      $unwind: "$roles"
    },
     // now repeat for each array in this document
    {
      $unwind: "$roles.assignedRoles"
    },
     // repeat again, since I need to look in the schools array.
    {
      $unwind: "$roles.assignedRoles.schools"
    },
     // The following line will return all records that the school ID checks out.
    {
      $match: {"roles.assignedRoles.schools.schoolId": school}
    },
     // $group is a necessary cleanup task so we avoid repeating employee records... Nicely Done! :) 
    {
      $group: {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "roles": {"$push": "$roles"},
      }
    }
  ])
    .exec()
    .then(function (docs) {
       // here you process the resulted docs. 
    });
```